# Xamarin.IOs gives an error "either upgrade Xcode or set the managed linker behaviour to Link Framework SDKs Only"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.IOs project. After doing some updates I am getting this error,

> This version of Xamarin.iOS requires the iOS 11.4 SDK (shipped with
>   Xcode 9.4). Either upgrade Xcode to get the required header files or
>   set the managed linker behaviour to Link Framework SDKs Only (to try
>   to avoid the new APIs).

How can I set the managed linker behaviour to **Link Framework SDKs Only**?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Right click on the **IOs project** and select *Properties*.

In the *Properties Window*,

[image]

Under **iOS Build** section, select **Link Framework SDKs Only** for **Linker Behavior:**.

That'll set the managed linker behaviour to **Link Framework SDKs Only**.

Comment: Is there a command line to do so?